# Using Cocoapods to Link React Native w/ Dependent Pods

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, cocoapods

I am having an issue w/ getting transient header linking errors in my ios build for my React Native project.

My react-native project is setup to use React.podspec in the node_modules/react-native/ directory in my RN project.

In my AppDelegate.m any imports of RTC* are imported by doing.

```
#import <React/RTCBridgeModule.h>
```

This works fine.

I am looking to add this library
https://github.com/devfd/react-native-google-signin and I would ideally like to use cocoapods to do the linking to keep things the same.

I have forked the repository and added a podspec file for this package here.
https://github.com/onlinegeek101/react-native-google-signin

The headers were failing when looking on

```
#import "RTCBridgeModule.h"
```

so I updated the imports to match the other  format on that fork.

I am now seeing that my build 'occasionally' will pass but other times will fail and say that it cannot find header

Does anyone have any thoughts/examples of how this should be configured or why I am seeing this behavior?

Comment: Did you have any further luck with this? I'm in a similar situation.